# Entity-Bean(in EJB) is a server side component?

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I am reading the *Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1 (Sixth Edition)* book .this book is told:

> *Entity beans, unlike session and message-driven types, **are not server-side** components.*

But in some places it is said(for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Bean)

> *An "Entity Bean" is a type of Enterprise JavaBean, **a server-side** Java EE component...*

I'm really confused:(.Which tell the truth ?Why is a server-side components?(or, Why not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3.0, the primary persistence for EJBs is JPA, which overloads the term "entity bean" to refer to JPA entities rather than entity EJBs.  JPA entities are not server-side components, but entity EJBs are.  So, both quotes are correct even though they seem paradoxical when they are missing context.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, you're encouraged to click the checkbox to the left of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

JPA can also be used in standard applications, without the need EJB CONTAINER.
In fact, when we use the JPA, we do not need EJB Context. JPA context is distinct from EJB context.